# HTML forms in Laravel blade foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm having trouble on controlling the limit of the forms seen on my page.

I have the first form with the select and the rest of the forms are generated inside a for each statement.

It should only display a single form using the @foreach which is based on the select option.

The code looks like this:

```
 <form>
    <select id="myselect">
        ...
    </select>
 </form>

 @foreach($students as $student)
     <form name="{{ $student->id }}" id="{{ $student->id }}">
         ...
     </form>
 @endforeach

 <script>
     $("#myselect").on("change", function() {
         $("#" + $(this).val()).show().siblings().hide();
     })
 </script>
```

I got that script from the internet, but it doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#myselect').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
         $('#1').show();
         $('#2').hide();
    }
});
```

this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are expecting, but, everything between your @foreach ... @endforeach will be repeated for every $student, so it will render as many forms as your students.

If you need to show only one form based on your selection on the top `<select>` you must write a javascript function, triggered by an onchange event on your select, that will show / hide your student's forms.

Comment: i already get what im needing using js but not in all selection.

this selected id's shows a form:
1pounder,
3pounder

but this ids dont:
express box small,
general cargo

why is that? i cant figure it out whats wrong with this ids